# Unable to check checkboxes inside SysTreeView32

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am trying to change Internet Explorer settings using AutoIt, but I can't check items in a SysTreeView32 using `ControlTreeView()`. My code :

```
var controlTreeView = "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]";
var treeView = AutoItX.ControlGetHandle(hwnd, controlTreeView);
AutoItX.ControlTreeView(hwnd, treeView, "Check", "#6|#6, "");
```

Code with command "Select" works fine, but it just selects the item.

```
var controlTreeView = "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]";
var treeView = AutoItX.ControlGetHandle(hwnd, controlTreeView);
AutoItX.ControlTreeView(hwnd, treeView, "Select", "#6|#6, "");
```

How can I (un-) check them instead of just selecting?

[image: item to check]

Comment: That is a very security-sensitive dialog that malware would love to mess with.  To what degree it is protected against robots is unclear.  Well, I would.

Comment: There are single checkboxes in other tabs, autoit recognizes them as buttons

Answer (score 0):

As help file for `ControlTreeView()` describes, the `Check` command only works "*if the item supports it*". Because of mentioned security-sensitive dialog, this command will not work.

**A solution:**

Use the `Select` command, focus the window/dialog and send a <kbd>space</kbd> keystroke:

```
Global $sWindow   = 'Internet Options'
Global $sControl  = '[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]'
Global $sCheckbox = '#6|#6'

Func _getTreeViewHandle()
    WinWaitActive( $sWindow, '', 2 )
    Return ControlGetHandle( $sWindow, '', $sControl )
EndFunc

Func _checkTreeViewCheckbox( $hControl )
    ControlTreeView( $sWindow, '', $hControl, 'Select', $sCheckbox )
    WinActivate( $sWindow )
    Send( '{SPACE}' )
EndFunc

Global $hTreeView = _getTreeViewHandle()
_checkTreeViewCheckbox( $hTreeView )
```

Tested in IE v11.

**Second approach:**

Adjust the registry with `RegWrite()`. Example:

```
Global $iReturnCode = RegWrite('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main', 'UseSWRender', 'REG_DWORD', '0x00000000')
```

You have to adjust the key for your OS version.